# How do I create a graph $G$ such that $G$ has fewer than $i$ vertices of degree at most $i\,\,\forall\, i<|V|/2$?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

> Let $d_i=d(v_i)$ with $1\le i\le n$. Let $D_k=\left\{v\in V\mid d(v)\le k \right\}$. Let $G$ be a graph such that $|D_k|<k \quad \forall\,k < n/2$.

Is there a way to create such a graph given an
$n\in\mathbb{N}$? I know that such a graph is not unique, but I need at least a few examples to analyze what's going on in a particular situation. I'm unsure where to begin specifically coding a graph given such parameters as $|D_k|<k\quad \forall\, k<n/2$.

Comment: With the IGraph/M package: If you create the degree sequence, then you can use `IGGraphicalQ` to check if its graphical, then `IGRealizeDegreeSequence` to create the graph.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the information. Once I figure out the code, I will post my answer here to complete the post.